# How to destroy all select2 selects that belongs to a specific class

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm developing a software in which all the select elements are using the select2 library.
In the footer there is this code to do that:

```
$('select').select2();
```

Now I'm developing a new screen that some selects will use select2 and others don't so I created the class ".noSelect2" for the ones that aren't supposed to have select2.
When I put this code, it only destroys the first select:

```
$('.noSelect2').select2('destroy')
```

What can I do to destroy all the elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using a class to target something with Select2 is that Select2, in the past, copied classes to the container elements so you could apply CSS there. As a result, using the class to target the `<select>` also resulted in targeting the `<div>` or other container element, and that would trigger an error.

The easy solution is to add `select` in front of your class selector, so it only targets the `<select>` elements.

```
$('select.noSelect2').select2('destroy')
```

---

In 4.0.0 [there is a known bug](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3413) with calling `select2('anything')` in that it isn't consistent when selecting multiple instances. This should be fixed by the next release (4.0.1) of Select2.

Comment: But i can only destroy the first select right? There is a way that i can destroy all the select2 elements that have the ".noSelect2" class? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That depends on what version of Select2 that you are using. It should work out of the box (with the modified selector) in 3.5.x and 4.0.1. In 4.0.0, you would need to loop over all elements and call it manually.